# Turning a random choice answer to and if statment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating  text based game in python 3.3.2 and I want to display a message depending on what happens after the attack either misses or hits *(chosen randomly)*, you get a different message depending on what happens. this is the code so far

```
print ("A huge spider as large as your fist crawls up your arm. Do you attack it? Y/N")
attack_spider = input ()
#North/hand in hole/keep it in/attack
if attack_spider == "Y":
   attack = ['Miss', 'Miss', 'Miss', 'Miss', 'Hit']
   from random import choice
   print (choice(attack))
```

I think it looks like this:

```
if attack == 'Miss':
   print ("You made the spider angry")
```

but this does not seen to work. is it possible to do this?

I added the code in the answer below like so:

```
               if attack_spider == "Y":
                   attack = ['Miss', 'Miss', 'Miss', 'Miss', 'Hit']
                   from random import choice
                   print (choice(attack))
                   messages = {
                   "Miss": "You made the spider angry!",
                   "Hit": "You killed the spider!"
                    }
                   print messages[choice(attack)]
```

but know when I run the program I get the error like so:

syntax error and highlights messages

did I just add the code wrong or it it something elese

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
result = random.choice(attack)

if result == "Miss":
    print("You made the spider angry!")
elif result == "Hit":
    print("You killed the spider!")
```

Note (as Matthias mentioned) that it's important that you store `result` here. If you did:

```
if choice(attack) == "Miss":  # Random runs once
    ...
if choice(attack) == "Hit":   # Random runs a second time, possibly with different results
    ...
```

Things wouldn't work as expected, as you may have `"Hit"` on the first random and `"Miss"` on the second one!

---

But better yet, use a dictionary:

```
messages = {
    "Miss": "You made the spider angry!",
    "Hit": "You killed the spider!"
}

print(messages[choice(attack)])
```

Comment: Deleted my answer. You were first and even provided a better way to do it.

Comment: @Matthias Cheers, I added a note inspired by your answer to explain why storing result was important.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco I added your code as you can know see in the question do you know how to fix the error

Comment: @dashernasher Please add the entire traceback to your question.

Comment: it does not show a traceback it just says invalid syntax and highlights messages in red

Comment: @dashernasher Difficult to tell without seeing more of your code, unfortunately.

Comment: Print is a function in Python 3, edited the answer so it should work now.